# How to upload files with python script

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

Is there a way to upload files from my PC to the Pepper robot using python script?

For example if there is some kind of function like

```
session.upload(file_path, robot_path)
```

Comment: this question doesn't show any research done on your side, please tell what you have tried and failed, or where you've looked so far, have you taken a look at the oficial documentation?

Comment: I have taken a deep look at the official aldebaran documentation but didn't find anything. My idea is if someone has any kind of info how it could be done to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use SFTP ?

In python:

```
import paramiko

ROBOT_URL = "10.80.129.69"

c_path = "wherever/that/is/on/the/computer"
r_path = "wherever/that/is/on/the/robot"

transport = paramiko.Transport((ROBOT_URL, 22))
transport.connect(username="nao", password="nao")
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.put(c_path, r_path)

sftp.close()
transport.close()
```